# Unable to render fields in node.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I'm trying to get individual fields printed on my node template, but am unable to get anything other than {{ content }} to work.

I'm using 8.5.0 and I'm not seeing any errors in the log. The page renders my markup so I know the template is being called.

Here's my node.html.twig markup:

```
    {%
     set classes = [
    'main-article',
    'main-article-page',
    ]
    %}
    {{ attach_library('classy/node') }}
     <article {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>

     <div class="main-article-image">
    {{ content.field_image }}  
     </div>

     <div class="main-article-body">
    {{ content.body }}  
     </div>

     </article>
```

Perhaps I've missed something in the setup of my theme?

Comment: Are you using field_layout? That is an experimental module and it completely changes the structure in entity templates

Comment: Thanks Berdir! You're absolutely right. Uninstalled Field Module layout and everything worked as it should.

Comment: Please: update your answer and ACCEPT it, so also others would know what the issue was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue to do with the Field Layout module. Once that was uninstalled my markup worked as it should.

Field Layout (and also Layout Builder module) moves Drupal towards theming within the UI, so if you're looking to theme with twig files, I'd recommend not installing them.